# Is it possible to run a shell off of a Flash Drive

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive

I have Ubuntu installed on a flash drive through pendrivelinux.com.  Is it possible for me to plug the drive into a Windows machine, then access the shell installed on the drive from the Windows machine (through a terminal emulator, I guess).  This would be *without* a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. You cannot run any application compiled for Linux natively on a Windows host (the binary format is not the same, system calls differ etc.).

There are ways of running a Linux (or Linux-like) shell on a Windows host, e.g. [Cygwin](http://cygwin.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're really asking (if I may be so bold), is to have ubuntu on your USB to boot to, but also have the ability to boot in to windows and access your ubuntu OS through an emulator - that's possible with QEMU. You'd be able to get a terminal/console through QEMU to access your data and access the OS. You could also use the GUI.

It looks like pendrivelinux.com has an article on how to do this [here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/all-in-one-pendrivelinux-2008/#more-422).

I realize the post is a bit dated, but I'm not very familiar with PDL, but I can't imagine they would have deprecated a feature they had in 2008.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple means of doing that. However if you are geeky enough, you can try [coLinux](http://www.colinux.org/). It provides a way of running native Linux applications **natively on Windows**. *No* virtualization softwares (e.g. Qemu/VirtualBox) needed, though you will need administrator privileges to install the driver.

But note that there hadn't been much new updates and it doesn't support Windows x64.

I am not going to give out a full step-by-step solution though, it could be quite complicated.

FYI, [Portable Ubuntu](https://sourceforge.net/projects/portableubuntu/) is a project that uses coLinux to allow running a full Ubuntu distribution natively on Windows. Impressive but a bit outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Fire up VirtualBox and boot it from the USB drive you have. [Read more](http://agnipulse.com/2009/07/boot-your-usb-drive-in-virtualbox/).